# How to make the cursor in a JTextField span multiple rows in FlowLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, flowlayout

[image]

How can I make the cursor start at the top left of the JTextField? The text just stays centered when I adjust the height with .setPreferredSize(). Here is the code for the fields and buttons.

```
public class GUIWindow extends JFrame{

    private JTextField inputBox = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField outputBox = new JTextField(20);
    private JButton encodeButton = new JButton("Encode");
    private JButton decodeButton = new JButton("Decode");

    public GUIWindow(){
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        outputBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
        inputBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
        outputBox.setEditable(false);
        mainPanel.add(inputBox);
        mainPanel.add(encodeButton);
        mainPanel.add(decodeButton);
        mainPanel.add(outputBox);
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a multiline control then you should use a [JTextArea](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) instead of JTextField.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. Thanks.